# Blazor: open new window with image from dynamic url

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor

I have a blazor server project and i navigate to a component like this
`_navigationManager.NavigateTo($"/DisplayTemplateRazor/{sub}");`

inside this component there is another component that i have created that is responsible for opening an image i click into a new window (like a pop up).

```
async Task ImageClickHandler()
{
    //open new window
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("newImageWindow", imageUrl);
}
```

just for reference also here is the js for opening the new window

```
window.newImageWindow = function (element) {
    try {
        var windowFeatures = 'width=600,height=400,top=100,left=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes';
        var newWindow = window.open('about:blank', '_blank', windowFeatures);

        if (newWindow) {

            newWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Full Image</title></head><body  style="margin: 0; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; height: 100vh;"><img src="' + element + '" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;"/></body></html>');
            console.log('Image loaded in new window: ' + element);
            newWindow.document.close();
        } 
        else {
            alert('Popup blocked! Please allow pop-ups for this site to view the image.');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('An error occurred while loading the image:', error);
    }
};
```

But the new window displays no image and when i click the inspector it says
"The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors"

So far i have figured out that the problem is that i try to open the new window from a component that i navigated to like i mentioned above
`_navigationManager.NavigateTo($"/DisplayTemplateRazor/{sub}");`

If I navigate to a link with just a href like this
`<NavLink class="nav-link" href="test2"> <span class="oi oi-book" aria-hidden="true"></span> Test </NavLink>`

Everything is working fine. So what am i missing? navigation messes up with showing the picture?

I have tried setting the URL of the new window into something default but no luck.
I also tried to encapsulate my navigation so that i don't pass a variable, but eventually i have to and the same thing happens again.

Comment: Is your image URL absolute, or relative? I'd guess the popup probably "inherits" its base URL from the location you are opening it _from_ in this situation, so if your image URL is relative, it likely simply resolves to the wrong absolute URL then.

Comment: Can you open DevTools and put a debugger in the JS and see what the value of `element` is?

Comment: thank for your replies! the element values was fine BUT also not fine. when i navigated to a uel just by an href the url was https://something.com/ so when i opened a new window with an image from Images/pic.jpg the result was https://something.com/Images/pic.jpg. When i was navigationg to a url with a dynamic value https://something.com/value there was no / at the end that caused all the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a component inside the Counter.razor and I've added a parameter to it.

```
@page "/counter/{StartCount:int?}"

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

<OpenImage Url="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></OpenImage>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int? StartCount { get; set; }

    private int currentCount = 0;

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        base.OnParametersSet();
        if (StartCount.HasValue)
        {
            currentCount = StartCount.Value;
        }
    }

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

This is the OpenImage component:

```
<p>
    Open image in new window:
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary ms-2" @onclick="@(e => ImageClickHandler(Url))">OPEN</button>
</p>

@code {
    [Inject] IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public string Url { get; set; }
    
    async Task ImageClickHandler(string imageUrl)
    {
        //open new window
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("newImageWindow", imageUrl);
    }
}
```

In the Home.razor I've added:

```
<button type="button" @onclick="OpenCounter" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Counter</button>
```

and in code:

```cs
private void OpenCounter()
{
  NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/counter/10");
}
```

you're javascript code is inside a site.js added to App.razor (Blazor 8):

```html
<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="@InteractiveServer" />
    <script src="site.js"></script>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>
```

all works fine with this implementation.

Comment: Well it might not have solved my problem directly but you sure helped a lot! to figure it out. I ran your example above and i tried to add my picture (which is in "Folder\\pic.jpeg"). When i opened it in a new window from a component with custom url i guess it would do something like this : https://<url>/CounterFolder/pic.jpeg which it doesnt do when you just navigate to a component because it adds a / at the end of the url by default.

so long story short i just needed to add "\\Folder\\pic.jpeg"

thanks again!!!